# return 0 instead of #N/A

Tags: excel-formula

`=IF(VLOOKUP($E5;$'S_BIP Purchase'.$G$3:$H$35;2;0)="PWP";SUMIFS($'S_BIP Purchase'.$L$3:$L$35;$'S_BIP Purchase'.$G$3:$G$35;$E5))`

Problem:

[image]

This formula works but it returns an #n/a. Can you please help me rephrase or enhance the formula so that it returns 0 instead of #n/a? I am using an openoffice calc

Answer (score 3):

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP($E5;$'S_BIP Purchase'.$G$3:$H$35;2;0)="PWP";SUMIFS($'S_BIP Purchase'.$L$3:$L$35;$'S_BIP Purchase'.$G$3:$G$35;$E5));"0")
```

IFERROR allows you to pick the value of the cell you want in case the formula returns error. IFERROR(Formula;Value)